# How to solve gradle; "contains too many directories after formatting system"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am developing an app using android studio and java. I downloaded gradle 6.1.1.zip and it was working fine. I formatted my system and installed android studio. I want to use the same gradle but I'm getting error.

```
file:/C:/sam/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip' contains too many directories. Expected to 
find exactly 1 directory.
```

The zip file contains only one gradle. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [android dev doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin), you can specify the gradle version either in:  File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` . In your case, for gradle 6.1.1.zip, you use the following in the above mentioned file:

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
...
```

Comment: I have done that but it is not working for me. it shows error in network connection but my system is connected to internet.

Comment: Do you have any proxy in your network? It could be a proxy related issue. If you have proxy, disable it . And can you please post the error message?

Comment: No. I don't have proxy on my system.